# Swapping out views inside one view controller on storyboard

Tags: ios, ipad, view, swap

[image: First View]

[image: Second View]

I'm currently trying to swap between these two views on the ipad.  Basically, I want the logo to stay in the same place, but swap out the email, password and sign-in with the forgot and continue the same way as a push view controller (push segue on the storyboard).

I'm currently trying to build two view on the storyboard that overlay over each other and then programmatically swapping the views by transitioning between them with
    transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:animations:completion
but I'm unsure that is the way to approach this problem.

To clarify, I don't want to move or swap out the Logo, which is why I don't just have this as another view controller...  but maybe I should do it this way instead?

Much thanks!

Comment: Design your *E-mail* and *Password* and *SignIn* view in a `UIView`, say *view1*, and *forgotPassword* and *continue* in another `UIView`, say *view2*. Then, remove the view1 using some animations and create view2 on completion block of `animation` i.e used to remove view1.

Comment: Do I have to design the second view programmatically if I want to have them in the same area on the app?

Comment: You can make it via xib also, but make the property `hidden` of `UIView` to be `YES`